# How to store output of a python program in command prompt?

Tags: python, shell, cmd, runtime, parameter-passing

I'm passing run time variable from command prompt to python to execute there (im=n python). Now I want to store the result of python program and use those results back into command prompt. Sample is as follows

```
set input=
set /P input=Enter Layer Name:%=%
C:\Python27\python.exe F:\xampp\htdocs\flood_publish\projection_raster.py %input%
```

I'm passing user input string to python program from command prompt as above.
How use the result of python program back into command prompt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me know if this helps.

**Code of python file (c.py):**

```
import sys

print('You passed ',sys.argv[1])
```

**Windows Batch Code (a.bat) :**

```
@echo off

set input=

set /P input=Enter Layer Name:%=%

(python c.py %input%) > tmp.txt

set /P output=<tmp.txt

echo %output%
```

**Output of batch code:**

```
C:\Users\dinesh_pundkar\Desktop>a.bat
Enter Layer Name:Dinesh
You passed  Dinesh
C:\Users\dinesh_pundkar\Desktop>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is depending on the case. If your Python code is exiting a value (with `exit(<returncode>)`), you can retrieve it from the `%ERRORLEVEL%` environment variable.

```
<yourpythoncommand>
echo Return code: %ERRORLEVEL%
```

If you are willing to capture and process the standard output, you need to use a `FOR` loop:

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%I IN ('<yourpythoncall>') DO CALL :processit %%I
GOTO :EOF

:processit
echo Do something with %1
GOTO :EOF
```

Now, if you don't want to process the output line by line, the easiest is to redirect the output to a temporary file.

```
<yourpythoncommand> >%TEMP%\mytempfile.txt
<do something with %TEMP%\mytempfile.txt>
del %TEMP%\mytempfile.txt
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming its a bash script from where you are calling the python function, it should be done like:

```
function callPython()
{
    local pythonResult=<code for calling python>
    echo $pythonResult
}

local pythonReturnOutput = $(callPython)
```

and you can now use pythonReturnOutput.

This answer may be incorrect, if you are not using bash, shell script. However, I would highly recommend to have a script in place, if its not already.

Comment: This is clearly not a bash script; OP is using Windows paths and explicitly references `cmd` in the tags.

Comment: Bash scripts do also work in Windows: http://www.howtogeek.com/261591/how-to-create-and-run-bash-shell-scripts-on-windows-10/

Comment: It is specific for Windows 10. What about windows 2008 server and windows 2012 server and other versions?